# Проблема с перезагрузкой программы на Python(Tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Создал программу на Tkinter, которая должна рассчитывать коммунальные услуги.
Программа работает но категорически отказывается перезагружаться, выдавая такую ошибку:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Artur\Soft\Python 3.7.1\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in 
__call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "F:\Python Middle\Экзамен.py", line 18, in start
    if not eleent1.get() or not eleent2.get() or not vodent1.get() or not 
vodent2.get() or not gazent1.get() or not gazent2.get():
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Долго гуглил эту проблему но ответ нашел только на англоязычном форуме, но даже с переводчиком ничего не понял.

Сам код:

```
#Python 3.6.1
from math import *
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

#window setings
window  = Tk()
#window name
window.title('Комуналка')
#window size
window.minsize(750, 600)
window.resizable(True, True)


def start():
    global eleent1, eleent2, vodent1, vodent2, gazent1, gazent2
    if not eleent1.get() or not eleent2.get() or not vodent1.get() or not 
vodent2.get() or not gazent1.get() or not gazent2.get():
        #Окно предупреждения
         messagebox.showwarning('Ошибка', 'Заполните все поля')  
    else:
        #исключение написания слов
        str1 = "0123456789" 
        if eleent1.get()[0] not in str1:
            #Сообщение об ошибке
            messagebox.showerror("Error!", "Вводите ТОЛЬКО числа!!!")
        elif eleent2.get()[0] not in str1:
            #Сообщение об ошибке
            messagebox.showerror("Error!", "Вводите ТОЛЬКО числа!!!")
        elif vodent1.get()[0] not in str1:
            #Сообщение об ошибке
            messagebox.showerror("Error!", "Вводите ТОЛЬКО числа!!!")
        elif vodent2.get()[0] not in str1:
            #Сообщение об ошибке
            messagebox.showerror("Error!", "Вводите ТОЛЬКО числа!!!")
        elif gazent1.get()[0] not in str1:
            #Сообщение об ошибке
            messagebox.showerror("Error!", "Вводите ТОЛЬКО числа!!!")
        elif gazent2.get()[0] not in str1:
            #Сообщение об ошибке
            messagebox.showerror("Error!", "Вводите ТОЛЬКО числа!!!")



        else:



            #Вывод значение
            eleent1= eleent1.get()
            eleent2= eleent2.get()
            vodent1= vodent1.get()
            vodent2= vodent2.get()
            gazent1= gazent1.get()
            gazent2= gazent2.get()

            eleent1= float(eleent1)
            eleent2= float(eleent2)
            vodent1= float(vodent1)
            vodent2= float(vodent2)
            gazent1= float(gazent1)
            gazent2= float(gazent2)
            #Расчет
            raznele= eleent2 - eleent1
            raznvod= vodent2 - vodent1
            razngaz= gazent2 - gazent1

            if raznele <= 90:
                grnele= float(raznele * 0.9)

            else:
                grnele= float(raznele * 1.68)

            grnvod= raznvod * 7
            grngaz= razngaz * 6.9579
            allsumma = grnele + grnvod + grngaz

            #Округление чисел(Дря коректного отображения)
            grnele = round(grnele, 2)
            grnvod = round(grnvod, 2)
            grngaz = round(grngaz, 2)
            allsumma = round(allsumma, 2)

            grnele=str(grnele)


    grnvod=str(grnvod)
            grngaz=str(grngaz)
            allsumma=str(allsumma)


            rezultele.config(text = grnele)
            rezultvod.config(text = grnvod)
            rezultgaz.config(text = grngaz)
            summa.config(text = allsumma)


#Объясняем
label1 = Label(text="Предыдущие значения", fg="#eee", bg="#333")
label1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)

label1 = Label(text="Новые значения", fg="#eee", bg="#333")
label1.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10)


#Расчет электричества
label1 = Label(text="Электричество(кВт)", fg="#eee", bg="#333")
label1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10)

eleent1 = Entry(window, font = 'Arial 20', bg = 'white', fg = 'navy', bd = 5, width = 10)
eleent1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10)
eleent2 = Entry(window, font = 'Arial 20', bg = 'white', fg = 'navy', bd = 5, width = 10)
eleent2.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10)

rezultele = Label(text="Сумма:", font = 'Arial 20', bg = 'white', fg = 'navy', bd = 5, width = 10)
rezultele.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=10)
#Расчет воды
label1 = Label(text="Вода(м³)", fg="#eee", bg="#333")
label1.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10)

vodent1 = Entry(window, font = 'Arial 20', bg = 'white', fg = 'navy', bd = 5, width = 10)
vodent1.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10)
vodent2 = Entry(window, font = 'Arial 20', bg = 'white', fg = 'navy', bd = 5, width = 10)
vodent2.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10)

rezultvod = Label(text="Сумма:", font = 'Arial 20', bg = 'white', fg = 'navy', bd = 5, width = 10)
rezultvod.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=10)
#Расчет газа
label1 = Label(text="Газ(м³)", fg="#eee", bg="#333")
label1.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10)

gazent1 = Entry(window, font = 'Arial 20', bg = 'white', fg = 'navy', bd = 5, width = 10)
gazent1.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10)
gazent2 = Entry(window, font = 'Arial 20', bg = 'white', fg = 'navy', bd = 5, width = 10)
gazent2.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=10)

rezultgaz = Label(text="Сумма:", font = 'Arial 20', bg = 'white', fg = 'navy', bd = 5, width = 10)
rezultgaz.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=10)






#Button
button = Button(window, text = 'Считать', width=10, height=2, command = start)
button.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=10)
#Сумма
summa = Label(text="Сумма:", font = 'Arial 20', bg = 'white', fg = 'navy', bd = 5, width = 10)
summa.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=10)




window.mainloop()
```

Comment: У типа float нет метода get.

Comment: А как это исправить?

Comment: Не пытаться вызывать метод `get` у чисел с плавающей точкой. Или не затирать такими числами переменные содержащие `Entry`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас переменные виджетов заменяются значениями которые вы расчитываете и после повторного нажатия на кнопку вы опять вызываете функцию переменной виджета, а у вас уже там значение чисел `float` после чего у вас и вылетаешь ошибка

```
# Python 3.6.1
from math import *
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

# window setings
window = Tk()
# window name
window.title('Комуналка')
# window size
window.minsize(750, 600)
window.resizable(True, True)


def start():
    if not eleent1.get() or not eleent2.get() or not vodent1.get() or not vodent2.get() or not gazent1.get() or not gazent2.get():
        # Окно предупреждения
        messagebox.showwarning('Ошибка', 'Заполните все поля')
    else:
        # исключение написания слов
        str1 = "0123456789"
        if eleent1.get()[0] not in str1:
            # Сообщение об ошибке
            messagebox.showerror("Error!", "Вводите ТОЛЬКО числа!!!")
        elif eleent2.get()[0] not in str1:
            # Сообщение об ошибке
            messagebox.showerror("Error!", "Вводите ТОЛЬКО числа!!!")
        elif vodent1.get()[0] not in str1:
            # Сообщение об ошибке
            messagebox.showerror("Error!", "Вводите ТОЛЬКО числа!!!")
        elif vodent2.get()[0] not in str1:
            # Сообщение об ошибке
            messagebox.showerror("Error!", "Вводите ТОЛЬКО числа!!!")
        elif gazent1.get()[0] not in str1:
            # Сообщение об ошибке
            messagebox.showerror("Error!", "Вводите ТОЛЬКО числа!!!")
        elif gazent2.get()[0] not in str1:
            # Сообщение об ошибке
            messagebox.showerror("Error!", "Вводите ТОЛЬКО числа!!!")



        else:

            # Вывод значение
            eleent_1 = eleent1.get()
            eleent_2 = eleent2.get()
            vodent_1 = vodent1.get()
            vodent_2 = vodent2.get()
            gazent_1 = gazent1.get()
            gazent_2 = gazent2.get()

            eleent_1 = float(eleent_1)
            eleent_2 = float(eleent_2)
            vodent_1 = float(vodent_1)
            vodent_2 = float(vodent_2)
            gazent_1 = float(gazent_1)
            gazent_2 = float(gazent_2)
            # Расчет
            raznele = eleent_2 - eleent_1
            raznvod = vodent_2 - vodent_1
            razngaz = gazent_2 - gazent_1

            if raznele <= 90:
                grnele = float(raznele * 0.9)

            else:
                grnele = float(raznele * 1.68)

            grnvod = raznvod * 7
            grngaz = razngaz * 6.9579
            allsumma = grnele + grnvod + grngaz

            # Округление чисел(Дря коректного отображения)
            grnele = round(grnele, 2)
            grnvod = round(grnvod, 2)
            grngaz = round(grngaz, 2)
            allsumma = round(allsumma, 2)

            grnele = str(grnele)

            grnvod = str(grnvod)
            grngaz = str(grngaz)
            allsumma = str(allsumma)

            rezultele.config(text=grnele)
            rezultvod.config(text=grnvod)
            rezultgaz.config(text=grngaz)
            summa.config(text=allsumma)



label1 = Label(text="Предыдущие значения", fg="#eee", bg="#333")
label1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)

label1 = Label(text="Новые значения", fg="#eee", bg="#333")
label1.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10)

# Расчет электричества
label1 = Label(text="Электричество(кВт)", fg="#eee", bg="#333")
label1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10)

eleent1 = Entry(window, font='Arial 20', bg='white', fg='navy', bd=5, width=10)
eleent1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10)
eleent2 = Entry(window, font='Arial 20', bg='white', fg='navy', bd=5, width=10)
eleent2.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10)

rezultele = Label(text="Сумма:", font='Arial 20', bg='white', fg='navy', bd=5, width=10)
rezultele.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=10)
# Расчет воды
label1 = Label(text="Вода(м³)", fg="#eee", bg="#333")
label1.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10)

vodent1 = Entry(window, font='Arial 20', bg='white', fg='navy', bd=5, width=10)
vodent1.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10)
vodent2 = Entry(window, font='Arial 20', bg='white', fg='navy', bd=5, width=10)
vodent2.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10)

rezultvod = Label(text="Сумма:", font='Arial 20', bg='white', fg='navy', bd=5, width=10)
rezultvod.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=10)
# Расчет газа
label1 = Label(text="Газ(м³)", fg="#eee", bg="#333")
label1.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10)

gazent1 = Entry(window, font='Arial 20', bg='white', fg='navy', bd=5, width=10)
gazent1.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10)
gazent2 = Entry(window, font='Arial 20', bg='white', fg='navy', bd=5, width=10)
gazent2.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=10)

rezultgaz = Label(text="Сумма:", font='Arial 20', bg='white', fg='navy', bd=5, width=10)
rezultgaz.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=10)

# Button
button = Button(window, text='Считать', width=10, height=2, command=start)
button.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=10)
# Сумма
summa = Label(text="Сумма:", font='Arial 20', bg='white', fg='navy', bd=5, width=10)
summa.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=10)

window.mainloop()
```